# Display List<String> from Apex class to Flow Screen Component

Tags: apex, automation, invocable-method, screen-flow

I have written a code which performs one particular automation. My objective is to display the output of type List string  in the screen component of flow.
When I try to create a new single record variable in the flow to display the output, I get this error **"The number of results does not match the number of interviews that were executed in a single bulk execution request"**.

Please let me know how I can modify the code or any change in the flow variables needed to display the output. Note: the code is working fine as expected when I run from Anonymous window.

**ps7Name** is just one variable in the list which is the input I am defining in the flow and passing to the code. My output will be the MissingList and AdditionalList lists. I have added one CombinedList also if needed.

Thanks

```
public class Persona_Test{

@InvocableMethod(label='Get User Details' description='Testing Persona Automation')


public static List<String> getUsersDetails (List <String> ps7Name)
{
    List<User> usrList = [SELECT Id, firstname, lastname, profile.name
                          FROM User
                          WHERE  Id IN (SELECT AssigneeId 
                                        FROM PermissionSetAssignment
                                        WHERE PermissionSet.label = :ps7Name)];
    
    Map <ID, User> usrMap = new Map<ID, user> ();
    for (User usr: usrList)
    {
        usrMap.put(usr.Id, usr);
    }
    
    
    
    //system.debug(usrList);
    
    //system.debug(usrMap);
    
    List<PermissionSetAssignment> PermList =  [SELECT AssigneeId, PermissionSet.label
                                               FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId = : usrMap.keySet()];
    //system.debug(PermList);
    
    Map<Id,List<String>> mapPermList = new Map<Id,List<String>>();
    List<string> StorePermSets = new List<String>();
    for(PermissionSetAssignment perm : PermList){
        if(mapPermList.containsKey(perm.AssigneeId)){
            List<String> temp =  mapPermList.get(perm.AssigneeId);
            temp.add(perm.PermissionSet.label);
            mapPermList.put(perm.AssigneeId,temp);
        }
        else{
            mapPermList.put(perm.AssigneeId,new List<String>{perm.PermissionSet.label});
        }
    }
    
    
    
    Map<ID, Integer> CountofPSMap = new Map<ID, Integer>();
    Map<ID, List<String>> MissingUser = new Map<ID, List<String>>();
    Map<ID, List<String>> AdditionalUser = new Map<ID, List<String>>();
    List<String> MissingList= new List<String>();
    List<String> AdditionalList= new List<String>();
    // to store the count of PS
    for (Id idvalue: mapPermList.keyset())
    {
        Integer count=0;
        for (String s: mapPermList.get(idvalue))
        {
            //system.debug(' Map keyset Id Value' + idValue );
            //system.debug(' list values : '+ s);
            count++;
            CountofPSMap.put(idvalue, count);
            
        }
        if (count<5)
        {
            String str = String.join( mapPermList.get(idvalue), ', ' );
            string concatenate='User ID:'+ '' + idvalue + ' '+ '' + 'PS assigned:' + str + '\n';
            //MissingUser.put(idvalue, mapPermList.get(idvalue));
            MissingList.add(concatenate);
            //system.debug('Missing PS User---->' + MissingList);
        }
        else if (count>5)
        {
            String str2 = String.join( mapPermList.get(idvalue), ', ' );
            string concatenate2='User ID:'+ '' + idvalue + ' '+ '' + 'PS assigned:' + str2 + '\n';
            //AdditionalUser.put(idvalue, mapPermList.get(idvalue));
            AdditionalList.add(concatenate2);
            //system.debug('Additional PS User---->' + AdditionalList);
        }
        
    }
    //system.debug(CountofPSMap);
    system.debug('Missing PS User---->' + '\n' + MissingList);
    system.debug('Additional PS User---->' + '\n' + AdditionalList);
    List<String> CombinedList= new List<String>();         
    CombinedList.addAll(MissingList);
    CombinedList.addAll(AdditionalList);
    return CombinedList;

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Even though your Invocable Apex Class is accepting List
2. But in the Flow you need to pass String value One by One